# CUDA Runtime API error 38: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: cuda, nvidia

**The Situation**

I have a 2 gpu server (Ubuntu 12.04) where I switched a Tesla C1060 with a GTX 670. Than I installed CUDA 5.0 over the 4.2. Afterwards I compiled all examples execpt for simpleMPI without error. But when I run `./devicequery` I get following error message:

```
foo@bar-serv2:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/bin/linux/release$ ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

**What I have tried**

To solve this I tried all of the thinks recommended by [CUDA-capable device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926016/380038), but to no avail:

- `/dev/nvidia*` is there and the permissions are 666 (crw-rw-rw-) and owner root:root

  ```
   foo@bar-serv2:/dev$ ls -l nvidia*
   crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Oct 24 18:51 nvidia0
   crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   1 Oct 24 18:51 nvidia1
   crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Oct 24 18:50 nvidiactl
  ```
- I tried executing the code with sudo
- CUDA 5.0 installs driver and libraries at the same time

**PS** here is lspci | grep -i nvidia:

```
foo@bar-serv2:/dev$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] (rev a1)
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [Quadro FX 1800] (rev a1)
```

**[update]**

```
foo@bar-serv2:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/bin/linux/release$  nvidia-smi -a
NVIDIA: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 295.59,
but this NVIDIA driver component has version 304.54.  Please make
sure that the kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components
have the same version.
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

How could that be, if I use the CUDA 5.0 installer to install driver and libs at the same time. Could the old 4.2 version, that is still lying around mess things up?

Comment: what happens if you run nvidia-smi -a  ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks for the input. I tried it, and it gives an error. BTW: where did you find out about this util?

Comment: Please explain your reasons to flag to close. Thanks!

Comment: There is no CUDA 5.0 package which lists Ubuntu 12.04 as supported.  You can check the [release notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt) for a list of supported OS's.  Something about your system config got in the way of a successfull driver upgrade.  You may want to review [nvidia driver readme](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.60/README/commonproblems.html) especially section 8 or search online for articles about failed driver installs on ubuntu.

Comment: Hm, so the driver installation can fail without the installer noticing and throwing an error? :(

Comment: Your kernel's driver module is out of date. This usually happens if the kernel sources present during driver installation do not match the running kernel, if the kernel is updated after installation of the Nvidia driver, or if no driver is installed at all. Check that your installed up-to-date kernel sources that match the running kernel and run the driver installation again.

Answer (score 14):

I came across this issue, and running

```
nvidia-smi
```

informed me of an API mismatch. The problem was that my Linux distro had installed updates that required a system restart, so restarting resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

See this stack overflow question [Installing cuda 5 samples in Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986701/installing-cuda-5-samples-in-ubuntu-12-10).

1. Ubuntu 12 is not a supported Linux distro (yet). For reference see [CUDA 5.0 Toolkit Release Notes And Errata](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt)

   **  Distributions Currently Supported

   ```
   Distribution       32 64  Kernel                 GCC         GLIBC        
   -----------------  -- --  ---------------------  ----------  -------------
   Fedora 16          X  X   3.1.0-7.fc16           4.6.2       2.14.90      
   ICC Compiler 12.1     X                                                   
   OpenSUSE 12.1         X   3.1.0-1.2-desktop      4.6.2       2.14.1       
   Red Hat RHEL 6.x      X   2.6.32-131.0.15.el6    4.4.5       2.12         
   Red Hat RHEL 5.5+     X   2.6.18-238.el5         4.1.2       2.5          
   SUSE SLES 11 SP2      X   3.0.13-0.27-pae        4.3.4       2.11.3       
   SUSE SLES 11.1     X  X   2.6.32.12-0.7-pae      4.3.4       2.11.1       
   Ubuntu 11.10       X  X   3.0.0-19-generic-pae   4.6.1       2.13         
   Ubuntu 10.04       X  X   2.6.35-23-generic      4.4.5       2.12.1
   ```
2. If you want to do it run on Ubuntu 12 anyway then see answer of [rpardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991614/56875). It looks like this distro instead of installing 64 bit libraries to `/usr/lib64` installs them to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

I'd suggest searching for all instances of `libcuda.so` and `libnvidia-ml.so` on the system. Since the driver doesn't support this distro it might have installed libraries to a path that is not pointed by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Then move the libraries around and/or change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to this location (it should be the first path on the left). Then retry `nvidia-smi` or `deviceQuery`

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is true, that I did not pay attention to the fact that CUDA 5.0 is not running on 12.04. The reason for that is, that CUDA 4.2 just worked fine on 12.04. I furthermore did what rpardo recommended while installing the driver the first time.

Comment: +!: Searching instances of `libcuda.so` solved it for me, in a different way: I had a left-over `libcuda.346.47` when the version I wanted and that came bundled with CUDA Toolkit 7.0 is 346.46. Since it was more recent, it would get picked up, and who knows that it did then. Deleting it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got error 38 for cudaGetDeviceCount on a windows machine with GTX980 GPU.
After I downloaded the latest driver for GTX 980 fro the NVIDIA site, installed it and restarted, everything is fine. Looks like the CUDA installer is not installing the latest driver.

Comment: Which version of cuda were you using? CUDA 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the sample using sudo (or, you might do a 'sudo su', set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path of cuda libraries and run the sample while being root). Apparently, since you've probably installed CUDA 5.0 using sudo, the samples doesn't run with normal user. However, if you run a sample with root, then you'll be able to run samples with the regular user too! I've not yet restarted the system to see if samples work with normal user even after reboot, or each time you should run at least one CUDA application with root.

The problem might completely disappear if you install CUDA TookKit without using sudo.

Comment: I recommend going back and reading the complete question again. This has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem on Debian and it turns out that loaded `nvidia` module had different version than `libcuda1`.

To check for installed `nvidia` module you should do:

```
  $ sudo modinfo nvidia-current | grep version
  version:        319.82
```

If it doesn't match version of `libcuda1` this the root of your problems.