# CUDA driver 4.2 version mismatch? 295.40 vs 295.41

Tags: cuda, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-12.04, nvidia

I'm trying to install CUDA 4.2 on my Alienware Aurora desktop system.  It's running Ubuntu 12.04, and Linux kernel 3.2.0-32 with an Nvidia GTX 690.  I am able to install the CUDA SDK and display driver without issue.  However, when Xorg starts, it dies with this error:

*Error: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 295.40, but the NVIDIA driver   component has version 295.41.  Please make sure that the kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components have the same version.*

The same thing happens when trying to run a CUDA application.  Any thoughts?  I have a lab of over a dozen other CUDA workstations which don't have this problem, but are also running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I guess I'd try to rebuild the kernel module. The process is described at the [NVIDIA graphics page at Debian.org](http://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Ubuntu 12 is not yer supported distro.

If you still want to run cuda on usupported platform and expose yourself to other such problems see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062766/56875