# Runtime API error 38 : no CUDA-capable device is detected / Ubuntu black screen

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, installation, desktop, drivers

I am currently trying to fix the following error:

Runtime API error 38 : no CUDA - capable device is detected.

I tryed to apply the advices given here: 
[CUDA-capable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925587/cuda-capable-device)
And I also tryed to apply other ones from the web.

The main issue is: when I rebooted my computer now, Ubuntu starts with command lines (with id and pass).

But I don't manage to get the Ubuntu usual desktop interface.

When I do CTL + ALT + F6 (or F something) then I can see something related to graphics drivers [fail] ed.

Do anyone know how to fix/restore the previous/initial Ubuntu graphics driver to come back to the previous state ?  I do use a Nvidia Geforce 620.

I am currently using the "try" version on the Ubuntu CD to write this message to you, I could not do it other way since I don't even access the Ubuntu desktop, because of this issue.

I believe there is a better solution than recovering the data and format/resetup, so I am ready to try, the thing is, I don't know how I could fix this issue with the use of command lines.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Gibo

Comment: Try running `sudo nvidia-smi -a` and report back what it says.  If you get an error, the error will be instructive.  If no error, try running your test again.

Comment: Timestamp                           : Mon Mar 31 00:49:41 2014
Driver Version                      : 331.20

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 0000:01:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GT 620
    Display Mode                    : N/A
    Display Active                  : N/A
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : N/A
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : N/A
 It seems they are mostly N/A ...

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVE UBUNTU/ZORIN - LINUX OS BLACK SCREEN

This is a gnome graphic error. I think window display manager got corrupted as it can't read the display libraries.
I had this problem on my zorin o 15.3 & when I researched i found that xserver needs to be reinstalled.

Step1 : Enter to tty2 (Ctrl + Alt + F2) & login with user credentials

Step2 : sudo apt-get autoclean

Step3 : sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

Step4 : If you get dpkg interrupted msg, run sudo dpkg --configure -a , else proceed to next step.

Step5: Reboot your machine - reboot